# Reinstallation of VS2015 after hard disk crash

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

I've a problem with VS2015 community edition reinstallation following a hard disk crash.

The initial situation :

- Drive C: is on a SSD dedicated to operating system (win10)
- Drive D: is an application drives, HD drive, VS 2015 is installed on it,

Everything works fine, but hard disk failure came, I have to replace the HD (D:), at this stage only personal data (codes for example) are backuped I don't backup the programs directories.

So...brand new HD, when I try to (re)install VS2015 community version: it fails. I had first some warning telling me some newer DLL/packages were existing on my PC (I've removed them), then after some setup retries I've finally a window telling me there is a package failure (no more info) and asking to reboot the PC to complete the setup.

After the reboot, I've tried to run VS2015, I see prompty the splashscreen telling me I'm running VS2015 community but after that I've got a white window with VS logo and that's all: I can only click on the x to close the window (the application is telling me I'm exiting VS2015)

Any idea, how to reinstall (or uninstall) properly vs2015 ? or bypass that window ? Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it could help some people, I've finally "fixed" the problem after one day of test/tries of some potential solutions. I've downloaded the .iso file of VS2015 from MS sit, and run the installation from it instead remote setup procedure.

The setup has been completed properly, I had some warning during at the first launch of the IDE, it asked me to restart: now, it seems ok, no more warning & I can compile sources etc...

Comment: since you already solved your issue by yourself, it is better to mark it as answer, that can help other community member to easier search your solution.